# putty disconects after a cople of minutes when using it to make a X tunnel for kvm VNC console

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, vnc, tightvnc

I am using putty from a windows desktop to make an X tunnel so I can access my KVM VMs VNC console (I am using TightVNC) but the putty connection dies after a few minutes.  I have other ssh connections from my windows box (actually using MINGW64 bash console) and it stays connected for a long time.  Any idea how to sort this out?

Comment: serverfault is for business purposes only. Please use superuser

Comment: I am doing this for a business.  I'm a freelancer setting up a server for a video production company.

Comment: try in putty keep alive